# Prove Amazon s3 file has been downloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip, aws-sdk

I'm selling music file downloads using PayPal. In order to get seller protection I need to be able to provide proof the file has been delivered.

From PayPal :

> If you sold a music download, then you might consider providing proof that you sent the buyer the link to the download and proof that they buyer accessed the download, giving dates and times (illustrative example only).

The files are stored in Amazon s3 and I'm using a ruby on rails project with 'asw-sdk' and 'paperclip' gems.

The file download link is shown after the PayPal checkout and is also emailed. Is it possible to prove the buyer accessed the download?

Comment: I think you can track by accessing through server log file. Another way is using cloud analytics service like qloudstat & S3stat  which gives you analytics from access logs of your S3.   

https://qloudstat.com/welcome
https://www.s3stat.com/

Comment: Enable logging on the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 2):

Use S3 [Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html), which, by default, will give you the IP address of any client that accesses the files in the S3 bucket.

If the users are authenticated into your application, you could also use the [Custom Access Log](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html) feature to pass the username into the request made to S3.

Comment: +1 but check this: if you use signed URLs, you can take advantage of an undocumented quirk in S3 by passing that query string parameter as something starting with `x-amz-meta-` e.g. `x-amz-meta-username=foo`. The front end auth code on S3 requires such an `x-amx-` parameter to be included in the signature for both V2 and V4 auth, but the backend ignores it, since `x-amz-meta-*` has no real meaning in the query string of a `GET` request. This prevents the user from tampering with the query string (it will invalidate the signature if they do) and your custom logging solution captures everything.